# Generic list doesn't contains AsQueryable() in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm writing my class library and after commit changes to git, application stop working - build ends with really strange error:

'IList' does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable' and no extension method 'AsQueryable' accepting a first argument of type 'IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Idea7.Entity;
using Idea7.Query;

namespace Idea7.Repository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Abstract in-memory repository
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class InMemoryRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {
        public abstract IList<TEntity> Data { get; }

        public long Count(IQueryObject<TEntity> query)
        {
            return query.Count(Data.AsQueryable());
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Fetch(IQueryObject<TEntity> query)
        {
            return query.Fetch(Data.AsQueryable());
        }

        public TEntity FetchOne(IQueryObject<TEntity> query)
        {
            return query.FetchOne(Data.AsQueryable());
        }

        public TEntity Find(TKey id)
        {
            return Data.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id.Equals(id));
        }

        public void Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            Data.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            Delete(entity);
            Create(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            Data.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Here is project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Idea7.Repository Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Sebastian Bušek" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnx50": { },
    "netcore50": { }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Idea7.Entity": "1.0.0-*",
    "Idea7.Query": "1.0.0-*",
    "Idea7.UnitOfWork": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you can't call a function that doesn't exist. AsQueryable can't be called from an IList.

Comment: Did you tried http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=AsQueryable ? It searches types and methods within packages and lists you the package which use it. It says `System.Linq.Queryable´, version `4.0.1-beta-23509`. Try adding a reference to it

Comment: On a side note, please don't use `dnx451` and `dnx50` moniker for class libraries. for ASP.NET Core RC1 you use `net451` for full framework and `dotnet5.x` (x=0-5) for .NET Core. `dnx451` and `dnx50` are only for applications (console, asp.net webprojects, xunit test projects)

Comment: Thank you for reply, your comment helped - I'm not sure, if someone in MS decided split package into small pieces, because this morning all worked well...

Comment: The whole .NET Core is heavy modularized, because now (soon, with RC2 and dotnet-cli) you can package all required assemblies with your application, so there won't be the need to install a runtime anymore and each application can use it's specific assembly versions side-by-side. So updating one application/framework (i.e. .NET 3.5 to 4.5.2) won't break your other applications anymore

Answer (score 2):

did you add this in your project.json references?

```
"System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
```

Answer (score 1):

AsQuerable is a part of the System.Linq assembly/namespace.

Comment: using System.Linq is in using section.

Comment: Is the using reference ok though? If it is, have you tried .ToList().AsQuerable()?

Comment: It was; but it seems like they broke package into small pieces. Tseng's response helped.